# sed replace but not between specific $ delimiters

Tags: regex, sed

I am using SED for windows.

I want to do a search and replace for all instances of character `_` replacing them all with character `-`

However I want to EXCLUDE those instance of `_` that are between two `$` `(i.e. in between two $ delimiters)`

So for the example string

```
123_abc$fred_1$abc_123
```

I want to replace the two outer `_` with `-`, but not the one inside the `$`

I have tried:

```
c:\ echo 123_abc$fred_1$abc_123 | sed /(\$*\$)/!s/_/-/g
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Great. A lot better than what I had. But I need the inverse.

The desired output is:

123-abc$fred_1$abc-123

So the _ between $ is preserved, but all of those outside of it become -

Comment: Are you looking for sed only answer or will be fine with awk also?

Comment: Any tool that works... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is easier using `awk`:

```
s='123_abc$fred_1$abc_123'
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="$"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/_/, "-", $i)} 1' <<< "$s"
123-abc$fred_1$abc-123
```

By using input delimiter as `$` we'll get all even numbered field that are between `$` hence we will need to replace `_` by `-` only in odd numbered field.

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -e ':cycle' -e 's/^\(\([^$]*[$][^$]*[$]\)*[^$_]*\)_/\1-/;t cycle' YourFile
```

Recursive modification discarting group of char between 2 `$`

Comment: This might be working but I am having trouble piping or redirecting the output to a file so I can look at it properly. If I use an -i option I think it breaks the recursion mechanism???

Comment: piping and `-i` together is generaly a bad idea with unexpected behaviour. (sorry i forget the first `^` in `s///`)

Answer (score -1):

This should work for a samples provided, if you have more underscores another tool like awk would be more appropriate.

```
sed -r 's/([^$]+)\$([^_]+)_([^$]+)\$([^$]+)/\1$\2-\3$\4/'
```

Comment: I got the original input back on my first try, but maybe I broke something.